# Send mail at particular time in action mailer using delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

```
def time_confirmation(user)
@user = user
if(@time == (Time.now()))
    mail(:to => user.email)
 end
end
```

Is this right? Mail has to be sent at current time.

Comment: Are you trying to send emails with headers that appear to be half an hour before they were actually sent? Or are you trying to send emails half an hour after they're enqueued/created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your controller do something like:

```
def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)
  DelayedEmailJob.new(@user.email).enqueue(wait: 30.minutes)
  redirect_to root_path
end
```