# send mail every 5 minutes using delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Testmailer < ActionMailer::Base
def test_mail
mail(:to => '(myemailaddress@removedforprivacy.com', :from =>   '(removedforprivacy)@gmail.com', :subject => 'Testing Delayed Job',  :content_type => 'text/plain').deliver
```

end
   handle_asynchronously :test_mail, :run_at => Proc.new {   2.minutes.from_now  }

end

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to send email every 5 minutes using `delayed_job` which is like a cron task. You can use [delayed_cron_job](https://github.com/codez/delayed_cron_job) gem to accomplish that purpose.

You can add: `delayed_cron_job` to your `Gemfile` and run: `bundle install`.
Then, run:

```
rails generate delayed_job:cron
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(DelayedEmailJob.new(@user.email), cron: '0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * *')
```

Comment: I tried this but getting errors..

Answer (score 1):

I answered that lately here [Send mail at particular time in action mailer using delayed job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32195345/send-mail-at-particular-time-in-action-mailer-using-delayed-job])

```
def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)
  DelayedEmailJob.new(@user.email).enqueue(wait: 5.minutes)
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: This one not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Using K M Rakibul's Answer, I have come up with this:

After installing `delayed_cron_job` gem and running `rails generate delayed_job:cron` and `rake db:migrate`, you can use it like

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue( DelayedEmailJob.new(@user.email), cron: '0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * *')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help...still I'm unable to solve this

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?